# How to derive a monoid's append from category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory

As I understand, a monoid $M$ is just a special kind of category; it has only one object and its morphisms can be composed through a composition operation. In principle, if $a$ is the object of the category, the composition operation should have the following signature:

$$
\circ:  (a \rightarrow a) \times (a \rightarrow a) \rightarrow (a \rightarrow a)
$$

However, in functional programming languages, the monoid's append has a different arity; for example in Haskell you have:

```
class Monoid a where
    mempty  :: a
    -- ^ Identity of 'mappend'
    mappend :: a -> a -> a
    -- ^ An associative operation
```

Ideally, categorical composition and `mappend` should be related i.e., we should be able to extract one from the other. But I cannot see why.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid . The categorical interpretation is an afterthought.

Comment: In particular, the monoid $a$ is not an object of your category, it *is* the category. It has one unnamed object $*$, so effectively $a=({*}\to{*})$, and composition is $({*}\to{*})\to({*}\to{*})\to({*}\to{*})$, that is, $a\to a\to a$. Emphatically, the morphisms ${*}\to{*}$ here are just abstract arrows, not any kind of functions, so it would be unhelpful to represent them as functions in Haskell.

Comment: IMO this question is appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ . Actually, this question is useful, because it reveals how superficial knowledge of category theory leads to believing that every morphism is a special case of a function.